# Should I consider Zend Framework 2 or go with ZF1 for an upcoming project

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm going to start work on a new Saas project. I've been working with Zend Framework for a few years now and was wondering on whether to move on to ZF2 i.e. it seems that ZF2 isn't backwards compatible with ZF1 and I was wondering how much of a learning curve is there to learning the Zend Framework 2 considering having a background in ZF1. I was interested in the notion of reusable modules in ZF2 as opposed to how they are implemented in ZF1. The stable release is quite recent for ZF2 and I would like to hear the opinions of people who have had the chance to use it.

In a nutshell given that I have to start on a project soon, is considering ZF2 a better idea since I'm assuming that a few modules available for ZF2 could help speed up my work a bit - or am I better off with ZF1 and different libraries?

Comment: Question is too subjective and most likely impossible to provide an answer. Only you really know.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, you understand the project requirements and timelines best; as such, you should take some time to estimate how much time you will need to learn ZF2 vs shoehorn ZF1 to do what you need.

If re-usable modules are a plus for you, however, ZF2 is definitely a better choice. Additionally, consider that ZF1 has a limited lifetime - we're looking at discontinuing support for it in 16-22 months.